# Regex to get part of image url (sublime text 3)

Tags: regex, image, url, text

I have a XML database containing several thousand positions. Text + html tags (images and links). I need a regex for Sublime Text 3 to replace a portion of the every image url (everything before file name).

For example, I have this:

```
<img src="/images/fanart/bigfana2121rt/215627676.jpg">
```

and

```
<img src="/images/screenshots/goodlooking/tret/215627676.gif">
```

And I need to get this:

```
/images/fanart/bigfana2121rt/
```

and this:

```
/images/screenshots/goodlooking/tret/
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us the regex you have written that isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Regex:

```
<img\b[^>]*\bsrc="([^"]*\/)[^\/"]*"[^<>]*>
```

Replacement string:

```
\1
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mQ4gG4/2)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but in Sublime Text 3 this regex selects whole img tag. I need everything before file name.

Comment: how i able to find the file name? Could you provide the format of filename?

Comment: like `<img\b[^>]*\bsrc="([^"]*\/)[^\/"]*"[^<>]*>(?=\s*foo.txt)`

Comment: for example in case of  `<img src="/images/fanart/bigfana2121rt/215627676.jpg">` it's `215627676.jpg`

Comment: try `<img\b[^>]*\bsrc="([^"]*\/)[^\/"]*\.\w+"[^<>]*>`

Comment: Nope. Whole <img> tag selected again.